# Does anyone know how to fix my mod not launching its something to do with 1.19.4 item groups

Tags: java, minecraft, minecraft-fabric

Whenever I run my mod I get errors:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Mixin transformation of net.blasted246.sizechanger.mixin.item.ModItemGroup failed
```

and

```
org.spongepowered.asm.mixin.transformer.throwables.IllegalClassLoadError: net.blasted246.sizechanger.mixin.item.ModItemGroup is in a defined mixin package net.blasted246.sizechanger.mixin.* owned by SizeChanger.mixins.json and cannot be referenced directly
```

I dont know what is happening, it is a 1.19.4 minecraft fabric mod on fabric loader 0.14.19.

My code:

```
package net.blasted246.sizechanger.mixin.item;

import net.fabricmc.fabric.api.itemgroup.v1.FabricItemGroup;
import net.blasted246.sizechanger.sizeChanger;
import net.minecraft.item.ItemGroup;
import net.minecraft.item.ItemStack;
import net.minecraft.text.Text;
import net.minecraft.util.Identifier;

public class ModItemGroup {
    public static ItemGroup SIZE_CHANGERS;
    public static void registerItemGroups() {
        SIZE_CHANGERS = FabricItemGroup.builder(new Identifier(sizeChanger.MOD_ID, "sizechangers"))
                .displayName(Text.translatable("itemgroups.sizechangers"))
                .icon(() -> new ItemStack(ModItems.SMALL_CHANGER)).build();
    }
}
```

I have already tried commenting out all references to it so the problem must be something in this file

Comment: maybe this question may help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68491171/error-when-trying-to-extend-a-class-using-mixin

Comment: Welcome on StackOverflow. Can you show the `SizeChanger.mixins.json` file? Also, are error complete ? Can you give more lines about errors?

Comment: @MatthiasDec it seems to be something else, for me it's not related. But, I'm the creator of the alone answer (':